# Spring data neo4j repositories not working since DATAGRAPH-939

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm using:

Spring-data-neo4j 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT (tried with 4.2.0.RC1 too)

and since the DATAGRAPH-939 commit, I'm not able to work with repositories anymore.

```
@Repository
public interface MyEventRepository extends GraphRepository<Event> {}
```

The error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myEventRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1466)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Here is an example of my failing test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { SimpleTest.TestConfiguration.class })
public class SimpleTest {

    @Configuration
    @EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.nagra.ml.sp.cpm.core.repositories.test")
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
            org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
        config  .driverConfiguration()
                .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver");
            return config;
        }

        @Bean
        public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
            return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "com.nagra.ml.sp.cpm.model");
        }

        @Bean
        public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

According to documentation, the way of declaring repositories seems to be correct, am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: There was a maven repository error around the time you raise this issue. Have you tried again with `mvn -U`?

Comment: I've tried again with 4.2.0.RC1 and 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (-U), I still have the same problem.

Comment: OK. If you haven't raised a Github issue then maybe to that. I'll try and investigate this today.

Comment: Thanks. Opened here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/384

Comment: Moved here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-950

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer have issues with repositories. I'm now using SDN 4.2.0.RELEASE with Spring boot 1.5.1 and I no longer extends GraphRepository as explained in SDN4.2.0 documentation.